# Recovering unsaved Juypter Notebook closed in VS code

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to recover my Jupyter notebook that was running on VS code but I was not able to do that. Any thoughts. i tried to use  `%history -g -f filename`. it did retrieve my code but not my markdown notes any thought how to get the Juypter notebook itself.